# Efficient way of Reading a very large text file from a specific line number to the end in C#

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

I have a requirement where I need to read a very large text file (~2 Gb), but only starting from a specific line number till the end of the file.

I can not load the whole text in memory due to performance issues. So I have used `StreamReader`. But I noticed that there is no easy way to start the "reading" from a specific line number, Rather what I have done is I have started to read the file from line 1, and ignoring all the lines before I reach my desired line number.

Is this the correct approach ? This is what I have tried. Is there a better way to achieving this?

```
static string ReadLogFileFromSpecificLine(int LineNumber)
    {
        string content = null;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(LogFilePath))
        {
            sr.ReadLine();
            int currentLineNumber = 0;

            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                currentLineNumber++;
                if(currentLineNumber >= LineNumber - 1)
                {
                    content += line + "\n";
                }
            }                
        }
        return content;
    }
```

Comment: IMO it looks correct, you load only relevent lines.

Comment: As (usually) lines in a text file all have different lengths, there is no way to jump to a specific line number without reading all lines before

Comment: To make it more performant you could use `StringBuilder content` instead of `string`

Comment: ^^ Or even better [`ReadToEnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=net-7.0) ...

Comment: Maybe this article will help too http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306822

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct approach. There is no algorithm to figure out the offset of a particular line and seek to it.

You may be able to squeeze a little more performance out of it by have two loops. Once the starting line is reached, you could move to the second loop, which wouldn't need to check the line number. But that would impact performance only minimally at best.

In addition, I'm not sure what you need to do with those lines. You can either process one line at a time and avoid loading all of them in memory at once. Otherwise, you could use a `List<string>` to build the list. Or if you want all the lines in a single string, use `ReadToEnd()`, as @Fildor recommended. Do not concatenate the lines as you are doing. That is extremely inefficient.

Comment: _"you could move to the second loop"_ or use `ReadToEnd`.

Comment: @Fildor: `ReadToEnd()` will work if he's adding all lines to a single string--I agree. But personally, I that isn't the way I'd store it.

Comment: Me neither. I just assumed OP wants to keep it being one string. I _may_ be wrong there, though.

Comment: @Bluemarble: _"That is extremely inefficient."_ because for each line, you'll create a string for the line read _and_ a new string that is the concatenation of the previous string and the currently read one. And all of them will stress GC.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using a `StreamReader` is the way to go (a `MemoryMappedFiled` is overkill in this case). But you can simplify it and hide the `StreamReader` and use `File.ReadLines` which does not read all lines into memory(as opposed to `File.ReadAllLines`). You should also use a `StringBuilder`:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(LogFilePath).Skip(LineNumber);
string content = new StringBuilder().AppendJoin(Environment.NewLine, lines).ToString();
```

Comment: Seems like `ReadToEnd()` would be more efficient than reading a line at a time and then concatenating them all together. That's great that `ReadLines()` doesn't load everything into memory at once, but then you'll loading it all into memory anyway.

Comment: @JonathanWood: at least the `StringBuilder` is just doing that once as opposed to OP's string concatenation. You're right, `ReadToEnd` would be the most efficient approach.